# How to select multiple options in dropdown in Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, user-interface, wicket

Is there a way to select multiple values in a dropdown in Apcahe Wicket using PropertyModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListMultipleChoice.

Say you have a list of users to which you want to populate in the multiselect drop down.
You can do something like this:

```
ListMultipleChoice<?> multiChoice = new ListMultipleChoice<Object> 
    ("usermultiSelect", 
     (IModel<? extends Collection<Object>>) new PropertyModel<Object>(properties,"selectedUsers"),
     users);
```

Furthermore you can register on change listener to do some stuff with the selected data

```
    multichoice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            List<User> users = (List<User>) properties.get("selectedUsers");   
            // do whatever you want to do with the users list
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use wicket Palette or use Select2. https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2/tree/master/wicket-select2-examples